# Are 2 instances of `std::hash<type>` equivalent?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdhash

Assume `my_hasher` is a hashing function object. Should the following be correct, according to the Standard?

```
 my_type k;
 assert(my_hasher{}(k) == my_hasher{}(k));
```

The [cppreference states](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) the above assertion is correct.

However, the Standard (16.5.3.4, [hash.requirements]) only requires that for a *specific* instance of `my_hasher`,

> the value returned shall depend only on the argument k for the
> duration of the program

...which seems like it *permits* 2 different instances of `my_hasher` to return different hash values for the same operand.

So, is cppreference mistaken or am I missing something?

Comment: It will be stable for the _"...duration of the program..."_ but if you re-run the program you may get different values for the hash;  ie don't store the hash in a file for later comparison purposes in subsequent runs of the program. See note - "_...[Note 1: Thus all evaluations of the expression h(k) with the same value for k yield the same result for a given execution of the program. — end note]..."_ https://eel.is/c++draft/hash.requirements#tab:cpp17.hash-row-2-column-3-note-1

Comment: As I understand it, the value returned must only depend on `k`, which implies that it cannot depend on `h`. So no matter what object `h` is, `h(k)` must be the same for the same `k`.

Comment: the title is a little misleading. the hash functor can actually differ while the produced hash can still be the same (not sure it's any useful).

Comment: @appleapple just wondered the same, because eg `std::unordered_map` has a constructor taking an instance of the hash. The hash instance could for example count how often it is called or stuff like that

Comment: How does that quote from the standard disagree with cppreference's writeup?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen it looks like the dependency on `h` is implicit and inevitable, because `h` is the function object that computes the hash. :)

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik it introduces a requirement, which is not explicitly stated in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

The requirements on specialisations of [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) can be more specific than the requirements in the concept [*Hash*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Hash).

Specifically `std::hash` is required to be [*DefaultConstructible*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultConstructible), whereas general *Hash*es aren't.

The requirement you are reading is that two default-constructed `std::hash<T>` objects compute the same hash, not that any two objects of some *Hash* type compute the same hash.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I've looked at 20.14.18 [unord.hash], it really requires a specialization of `std::hash` to be `DefaultConstructible`, but again, it only requires that (k1 == k2) ==> (h(k1) == h(k2)). It says nothing about the equivalence of default-constructed instances (which might use e.g. some global seed).

Comment: @IgorR. there's [a general prohibition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/res.on.data.races) on functions in `std` from accessing global values

Comment: IUUC, it only speaks about data races, i.e. a global state may be accessed using a proper synchronization. Or let's say we're in a single-threaded environment.

Comment: "This means, for example, that implementations can't use a static object for internal purposes *without synchronization*" - i.e. it may use it *with* synchronization.

Comment: @IgorR. I think it's a hole in the standard, because it doesn't require `std::hash` be *EqualityComparable*, and require equal hashers to result in equal hashes, thus moving nodes between unordered maps might break